# MySQL: Excluding

Tags: mysql

I have a database table called '`members`'. Assigned to members is a `position`.

`Positions` come from `Departments`. I have `Departments`, then `Sub-Departments` within those and Positions within the Sub-Departments.

Hopefully I haven't lost you.

What I want to do is is select all the members within a department, excluding any of those members from one position within that department.

"departments" Table: (includes departments and sub-departments)

```
ID     NAME                  PARENT_ID
1      Department #1         NULL
2      Department #2         NULL
3      Sub Department #1     1       
4      Sub Department #2     1       
5      Sub Department #3     2
```

"departments_positions" Table:

```
ID     NAME             SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID
1      Position #1      3
2      Position #2      3
3      Position #3      4
```

"members_positions" Table:

```
ID     MEMBER_ID     POSITION_ID
1      1             1
2      1             2
3      1             3
```

Here's my MySQL code:

```
SELECT m.* FROM members AS m 
    LEFT JOIN members_positions AS mp ON mp.member_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN departments_positions AS dp ON mp.position_id = dp.id
    LEFT JOIN departments AS sd ON dp.sub_department_id = sd.id
    LEFT JOIN departments AS d ON sd.parent_id = d.id
    WHERE mp.position_id != '2' AND d.id = '1'
    GROUP BY m.id
```

So as you can see I want to extract the members that are in "Department #1" (ID: 1 from departments_table) but not members who are in Position #2 (ID: 2 from departments_positions table) of that department.

Hopefully I am making sense. My code above doesn't seem to work. It just exports everyone from the department.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are using LEFT JOIN, which will not filter data.

Change your query to use INNER JOIN.

You also cannot use a select * if you're grouping by member id.

*Edit: I inputed your tables into a local mysql db and confirmed this query working.*

```
SELECT DISTINCT mp.member_id
FROM        members_positions mp
INNER JOIN  departments_positions dp ON dp.id = mp.position_id
    AND     mp.position_id != 2
INNER JOIN  departments sd on sd.id = dp.sub_department_id
    AND     sd.parent_id = 1
GROUP BY    mp.member_id
```

Also, any reason why you're quoting your int values 2 & 1 in the where statement?

If you only want the unique member id's, you don't need to do a `GROUP BY`. You should switch your select to this and then use an outer select to get all the member info:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM members m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT mp.member_id
    ... the rest...
) innerQ ON innerQ.member_id = m.id
```

Comment: I didn't ignore it, you had SELECT DISTINCT against the point where you had selected from the entire members table and were SELECT DISTINCTing the whole table.  I suggested doing it a level above so that members is only accessed once you know which rows you want are able to access by PK alone.   Even with your additions, our answers are not equal, and I am quite certain that I suggested would prove optimal under load.  Also I suggested NOT joining departments onto itself.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net I was not disputing the unnecessary join, and no, I was not selecting from the whole member table. Was only selecting the member id in all examples.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to avoid GROUP BY and potentially large joins where possible and so would look at the following

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM members AS m 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT mp.member_id
    FROM members_positions AS mp
    INNER JOIN departments_positions AS dp 
        ON dp.id = mp.position_id
        AND dp.id != 2
    INNER JOIN departments AS sd
        ON sd.id = dp.sub_department_id
        AND sd.parent_id = 1
) AS validMembers
ON validMembers.member_id = m.id
```

First of all, you don't need to join `departments` twice.  This is because you are joining `sd.parent_id = d.id` however then limiting it to instances where `d.id = 1`.  You can condense these and so remove `join, giving`sd.parent_id = 1`.

Now moving down a bit, INNER JOIN up to `member_positions, restrict it to instances where`mp.position_id != 2`and select the`DISTINCT mp.member_id`.  So far these are all nice simple joins with minimal data required.

Finally this list is joined onto members, and so now the full data from members is retrieved only for those rows you are interested in.

To further increase the speed of this the following indexes (in this field order) would probably be beneficial (assuming they don't exist already of course).

```
member_positions INDEX (position_id, member_id)
department_positions INDEX (sub_department_id) -- assumes id is the PK
departments INDEX (parent_id) -- assumes id is the PK
```